# No idea why a suggested edit fixing formatting and typos was rejected as "defacement"

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I am not sure what to do, and do not know why [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15145876) was rejected indicating that the post was defaced.  I reformatted and fixed some typos to help out a new user.

I don't know the next step to address this.

Comment: Likely because the post's owner doesn't understand the site and didn't like that someone else was trying to edit their post. Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize it was the new user.  Thank you, it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: FWIW Edit applied

Comment: I don't get the downvotes on the question though, I'm not a Mac user so maybe it's obvious, but the Q seems reasonably scoped and the OP seems to have spend some time to research. OTOH I did vote to close as I think I did found a correct duplicate.

Comment: @animuson: Until you find yourself getting enough of your edits rejected by new users who don't know better, that you get [banned from suggesting edits for edits that were otherwise completely appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252058/dont-consider-post-owner-decisions-when-serving-edit-bans).

Comment: @Tensibai I originally read your first comment as "FWIW Edit appalled", completely different meaning.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that edit it should have been accepted. The user is new though and probably needs educating in the ways of SO format foo.

Comment: @Tensibai I don't and here's why, what is the question? I see an error, what they think could be the problem, but no question.

Comment: It looks like it might have even been an accident on the part of the OP rather than actual disapproval of your edit. They made a minor edit about the same time, and I think that automatically rejects pending edit suggestions, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Lanky well, I assume we're all adult enough to guess OP's question is to understand why Apache doesn't take the proper library and how to solve it. Stating it explicitly would only be fuss IMHO...

Comment: @Don'tPanic If it was an automatic reject, the reject reason would have been different. The OP explicitly chose _"This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive."_

Comment: [The OP explicitly chose chaos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UtHc.png)

Comment: @Tensibai adult enough has nothing to do with it, either the question is clear or it isn't. It isn't our job to second guess what they are asking. You did the right thing though [asking them to edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117309/subversion-and-apache-httpd-conf-integrated-problems#comment71407470_42117309) adding the extra detail, which so far has been ignored.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you didn't have evidence, I could claim ignorance... Too bad I'm not too good with the force.

Comment: @Kendra May the force be with you.

Comment: @Kendra You're right, of course. Not sure how I missed that fact.

Comment: @Landry I hope so, I just added one more comment to guide the OP,  but frankly this question is better than a bunch of crap we see daily, there's sign the OP did try to understand it, that's enough for me to be 'helping' as much as I can, but as I said I'm out of my domain so I'm not of much help. I had hope someone on Meta would answer it :/

Comment: Blame autocorrect,  previous comment was aimed at @Lanky sorry ;) Note for myself: don't comment from phone at 11:15pm

Comment: Is the question really as horrible as the current -9/+1 voting suggests (not familiar enough with the setup to judge); or is the meta effect attack mob blasting it at full force?

Comment: @DanNeely: imho, the question is a valid one, but the - vote isn't.

Comment: Another time, please ([**use code formatting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)) for errors. It is **much** easier to read errors in code formatting, particularly when the errors are long and/or contain helpful line breaks. Please *do not* use quote formatting in these cases as it *removes* the original line breaks in the error text, making it harder to read. It does not just display the text differently, but the line breaks are actually *removed* and unrecoverable without going to a prior version. Because of this, I will often reject-and-edit such edit suggestions.

Comment: However, in this specific case, the line breaks in the error text had already been removed, or were not existent in the original version of the question. As a result, nothing was lost in using quote formatting. Thus, quote formatting was arguably a reasonable choice for the error text as it existed in the original version of *this* question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your edit was correct. The OP, a low-rep and new user, rejected it. The OP will always have a binding accept/reject vote for edits on their posts.

Asking for clarification here is always on-topic, when you're not sure what you could do better. In this case, you did right and the other user seems to just misunderstand the site and its ways.

I don't suggest resubmitting your edit- Now that this is on Meta, a higher rep user who doesn't have to go through review can make the changes.

Comment: Ya know, I just realized *right now* that you actually included the darth vader face in your avatar after the hat madness was over.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yeah, I've had a vader mask for two years now- I used the one for the 2015 winter bash, and updated it the first day of the 2016 winter bash when I got the new hat. :) Either it just completely flew under your radar, or Vader belongs and no one looked twice when they saw him.

Comment: Some sith mind control going on there for sure